# Measuring overflow is incorrect in Vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm trying to make a overflow with tagging, which fades out in the beginning to give the user a hint that there's more. This is what it looks like:

[image: Almost finished tagsinput full with tags with fading tags at the beginning]

I put the fading gradient as a `:after` inside the CSS and "activate" it by Vue's [style binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html), when `scrollWidth > offsetWidth` (overflow bigger than the box itself).

But the problem is that it sometimes (lags?) behind and does not calculate the scrollWidth right, especially when I enter a long word and then delete it. It doesn't "like" that and it says that the overflow is false, but there's no tag in the box. Basically this happens:
[image: Calc reports wrong and text is fading at the beginning, but there's no overflow happening]

I tried to put the calculation inside this `$nextTick()`, but it didn't solve the issue. I also tried using Vue's `keyDown`, `keyUp` and `keyPress` listeners, but nothing solved this also.

This (also on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BMmaxw)) demonstrates the issue:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#tagsinput',
  data: {
    input_value: "",
    tags: []
  },
  methods: {
    addTag: function() {
      if (this.input_value > "") {
        this.tags.push(this.input_value)
        this.input_value = "";

        // Refocus the text input, so it stays at the end
        this.$refs.input.blur();
        this.$nextTick(function() {
          this.$refs.input.focus();
        })

      }
    },
    deleteTag: function() {
      if (this.input_value == "") {
        this.tags.pop()
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.outter {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.inner {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 2px;
  display: flex;
}

.tag {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 2px;
}

input {
  min-width: 80px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="tagsinput">
  <div class="outter" ref="outter">
    <div class="inner" ref="inner">
      <div class="tag" v-for="tag in tags">{{tag}}</div><input type="text" v-model="input_value" @keydown.enter="addTag" @keydown.delete="deleteTag">
    </div>
  </div>
  Outter div scrollwidth: {{ $refs.outter ? $refs.outter.scrollWidth : null }}<br> Outter div offsetWidth: {{ $refs.outter ? $refs.outter.offsetWidth : null }}<br>
  <br> Is overflowing: {{ ($refs.outter ? $refs.outter.scrollWidth : null) > ($refs.outter ?$refs.outter.offsetWidth : null) }}
</div>
<br><br> Type a really long word in, add and then delete it. "Is overflowing" will be the inverse, until you press Backspace <b>again</b>.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the check for overflow after the moment you've added or deleted the tag, so you check the overflow at the right moment. Vue isn't databinding an inline condition like that. The following code should work for you. It calls a `checkOverflow` function within `$nextTick`, setting a data-binded variable `isOverflowed` that you then can use to bind some styles.

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#tagsinput',
    data: {
        input_value: null,
        tags: [],
        isOverflowed: false
    },
    methods: {
        addTag: function() {
            if(this.input_value) {
                this.tags.push(this.input_value)
                this.input_value = null;

                // Refocus the text input, so it stays at the end
                this.$refs.input.blur();
                this.$nextTick(function() {
                    this.$refs.input.focus();
                    this.checkOverflow()
                })
            }
        },
        deleteTag: function() {
            if(!this.input_value) {
                this.tags.pop()
                this.$nextTick(function() {
                    this.checkOverflow()
                })
            }
        },
        checkOverflow: function() {
            this.isOverflowed = (this.$refs.outter ? this.$refs.outter.scrollWidth : null) > 
                (this.$refs.outter ? this.$refs.outter.offsetWidth : null)
        }
    }
})
```

```css
.outter {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
}

.inner {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: 2px;
    display: flex;
}

.tag {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 2px;
}

input {
    min-width: 80px;
    width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="tagsinput">
    <div class="outter" ref="outter">
        <div class="inner" ref="inner">
            <div class="tag" v-for="tag in tags">{{tag}}</div>
            <input type="text" v-model="input_value" @keydown.enter="addTag" @keydown.delete="deleteTag" ref="input">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    Is overflowing: 
    {{ isOverflowed }}
</div>
<br><br>
Type a really long word in, add and then delete it. "Is overflowing" will be the inverse, until you press Backspace <b>again</b>.
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This works just fine and I just discovered why my previous attempts all failed: When using `vue2-transitions` to show and hide the "chips", while fading over 200ms, the width *will be wrong* and nextTick will still report the longer width (which is wrong). I now disabled the transitions until I find a solution for that (setTimeout is inconsistent).

Comment: Oh wow, that's nice! Solved this and some other transition problems too :)

Answer (score 0):

More of a CSS/HTML hack ...

Add `<div id="spaceFade"></div>` after `<div id="tagsinput">`, then add the following CSS :

```css
#spaceFade {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  position : absolute;
  height : 2em;
  width : 3em;
}
#tagsinput {
  position : relative;
}
.outter {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```